# API request is failing using redux-saga in react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I want to load products in home page. I decided to implement using `redux-saga` to take care of side effect. API call is failing in redux saga. Here is code. Can you please tell me what going wrong?

Api.js

```
export const getProducts = async (sort, order, page) => {
  return await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/products`, {
    sort,
    order,
    page,
  });
};
```

porduct.saga.js

```
import { takeEvery, call, put, all } from "redux-saga/effects";

import ProductActionTypes from "./product.types";

import {
  loadLatestArrivalProductSuccess,
  loadLatestArrivalProductFail,
} from "./product.actions";

import { getProducts } from "./Api";

export function* fetchLatestArrivalProducts() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getProducts("createdAt", "desc", 1));
     // it's failing inside try
    yield put(loadLatestArrivalProductSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loadLatestArrivalProductFail(error));
  }
}

export function* fetchLatestArrivalProductsStart() {
  yield takeEvery(
    ProductActionTypes.LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_START,
    fetchLatestArrivalProducts
  );
}

export function* productSagas() {
  yield all([call(fetchLatestArrivalProductsStart)]);
}
```

product.reducer.js

```
import ProductActionTypes from "./product.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: [],
  loading: false,
  page: 1,
  errorMessage: undefined,
};

const productReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ProductActionTypes.LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case ProductActionTypes.LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload,
      };
    case ProductActionTypes.LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productReducer;
```

product.type.js

```
const ProductActionTypes = {
  LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_START: "LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_START",
  LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS: "LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS",
  LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_FAIL: "LOAD_LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_FAIL",
  LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_COUNT: "LATEST_ARRIVAL_PRODUCT_COUNT",
};

export default ProductActionTypes;
```

Here is backend code to list all products on home

```
 exports.list = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const { sort, order, page } = req.body;
    const currentPage = page || 1;
    const perPage = 3;

    const products = await Product.find({})
      .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
      .populate("category")
      .populate("subs")
      .sort([[sort, order]])
      .limit(perPage)
      .exec();

    res.json(products);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what the failure is? Is there a network request error? An error processing the response? Any console errors? A stacktrace? SO isn't really a debugging service. Is there any other information you can provide other than "it's not working"?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getProducts` function in your saga, you should set the args after the function as params.

```
export function* fetchLatestArrivalProducts() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getProducts, "createdAt", "desc", 1);
     // it's failing inside try
    yield put(loadLatestArrivalProductSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loadLatestArrivalProductFail(error));
  }
}
```

**Update**

If you want to pass prop to saga

```
export function* fetchLatestArrivalProducts(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(getProducts, "createdAt", "desc", action.page);
     // it's failing inside try
    yield put(loadLatestArrivalProductSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loadLatestArrivalProductFail(error));
  }
}
```

Comment: np, you can check the answer if it works.

Comment: It is working. I need one help. How can i pass parameter in saga file ?                  
  const response = yield call(getProducts("createdAt", "desc", 1)); I want this way  const response = yield call(getProducts("createdAt", "desc", page)); i.e. 1 which i am passing from component. How can i achieve this one ?

Comment: plz check my code. you can add params after the function name

Comment: Currently it is  const response = yield call(getProducts, "createdAt", "desc", 1); I need help to write in this way  const response = yield call(getProducts, "createdAt", "desc", page); page variable value is coming from component

Comment: It is feasible to use reducer state in saga file ?

Comment: I have added an answer where i am facing issue related passing props to saga file

Comment: Able to do now. Thanks a lot

Comment: please check my answer then

Comment: I have posted another doubt over stackover flow. See if you can resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446530/how-to-show-updated-array-of-object-list-item-when-state-is-update-in-reducer-us